# Read in azure blob using python

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I want to read an excel file stored in Azure blob storage to a python data frame. What method would I use?

Comment: You may refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#code-examples) and this [page](https://aakashkh.github.io/azure/python/2018/12/22/Connection-Azure-Blob.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a function named [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel) in the `pandas` package, which you can pass a url of an online excel file to the function to get the dataframe of the excel table, as the figure below.

[image]

So you just need to generate a url of a excel blob with sas token and then to pass it to the function.

Here is my sample code. Note: it requires to install Python packages `azure-storage`, `pandas` and `xlrd`.

```
# Generate a url of excel blob with sas token
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

account_name = '<your storage account name>'
account_key = '<your storage key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'
blob_name = '<your excel blob>'

blob_service = BaseBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)

sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
blob_url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)

# pass the blob url with sas to function `read_excel`
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(blob_url_with_sas)
print(df)
```

I used my sample excel file to test the code below, it works fine.

Fig 1. My sample excel file `testing.xlsx` in my `test` container of Azure Blob Storage

[image]

Fig 2. The content of my sample excel file `testing.xlsx`

[image]

Fig 3. The result of my sample Python code to read excel blob

[image]

Comment: This gives an http 400 error when trying to get blobs from nested files (ex. it works fine with folder/file but not folder/folder/file), do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @dragonfromdreamsd Please create a new SO thread to post the details of your issue, and then I will help you.

Comment: no such module: `from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService`

Comment: @mas Please check the version of Azure Storage SDK that be old v2 or new v12.

Comment: thank Peter, the second solution in this post worked for me. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825744/read-excel-data-from-azure-blob-and-convert-into-csv-using-python-azure-function)