# Download XLSX File from Azure Blob in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, azure, download

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=AZURE_ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=AZURE_ACCOUNT_KEY)
file = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(AZURE_CONTAINER, "CS_MDMM_Global.xlsx")
file.content // the issue is at this line it give me data in some encoded form, i want to decode the data and store in panada data frame.
```

I'm getting encoded data from blob but I'm unable to figure out how I will decode the data to PANDA DATAFRAME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to read the content of a `xlsx` blob file stored in Azure Blob Storage via `pandas` to get a pandas dataframe.

I have a `xlsx` sample file stored in my Azure Blob Storage, its content is as the figure below.

[image]

So I will directly read it by Azure Storage SDK for Python and `pandas`, the first step is to install these packages below.

```
pip install pandas azure-storage xlrd
```

Here is my sample code.

```
# Generate a url of excel blob with sas token
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

account_name = '<your storage account name>'
account_key = '<your storage key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'
blob_name = '<your excel blob>'

blob_service = BaseBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)

sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
blob_url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)

# pass the blob url with sas to function `read_excel`
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(blob_url_with_sas)
print(df)
```

And the result is:

[image]

Actually, your post question is duplicated with the other SO thread [Read in azure blob using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829646/read-in-azure-blob-using-python/58851055#58851055), for more details, please refer to my answer for it.