# Read excel data from Azure blob and convert into csv using Python azure function

Tags: python, azure, io

I would like to deploy azure function  with following functionality

1. read excel data from Azure blob into stream object instead of downloading onto VM.
2. read into data frame
   I  require help to read  the excel file to into data frame. How to update placed holder download_file_path to read excel data .

```
    import pandas as pd 
    import os 
    import io
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient,BlobServiceClient,ContentSettings
        
    connectionstring="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
    excelcontainer = "excelcontainer"        
    excelblobname="Resource.xlsx" 
    sheet ="Resource" 
            
    blob_service_client =BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connectionstring)
    download_file_path =os.path.join(excelcontainer)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=excelcontainer, blob=excelblobname)
    with open(download_file_path, "rb") as f:
       data_bytes = f.read()
    df =pd.read_excel(data_bytes, sheet_name=sheet, encoding = "utf-16")
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what you try?

Comment: I wrote script to download blob(Excel)  on to local and read the data using pandas into dataframe . From data frame , data is pushed into csv file . This csv file is uploaded to blob. When deployed into Azure function , its failing .    Instead of downloading ,I am trying to stream data from blob and push it into data frame .  Its failing at   `with open(download_file_path, "rb")` its not able to find resource

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to read an excel file from Azure blob with panda, you have two choice

1. Generate SAS token for the blob then use blob URL with SAS token to access it

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobSasPermissions, generate_blob_sas
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    account_name = 'andyprivate'
    account_key = 'h4pP1fe76*****A=='
    container_name = 'test'
    blob_name="sample.xlsx"
    sas=generate_blob_sas(
      account_name=account_name,
      container_name=container_name,
      blob_name=blob_name,
      account_key=account_key,
      permission=BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
      expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
    )

    blob_url = f'https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}?{sas}'
    df=pd.read_excel(blob_url)
    print(df)
    ......
```

[image]

2. Download the blob

```
from azure.storage.blob import  BlobServiceClient
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    account_name = 'andyprivate'
    account_key = 'h4pP1f****='

    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f'https://{account_name }.blob.core.windows.net/', credential=account_key)
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container='test', blob='sample.xlsx')
    downloader =blob_client.download_blob()
    df=pd.read_excel(downloader.readall())
    print(df)
    ....
```

[image]

Comment: @VenkatSuryaSunilmodekurthy Since it is useful for you, could you please [accept it as an asnwer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)? It may help more people who have similar issue。

Comment: how we can upload an excel file in blob?

Comment: @mas you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#upload-blobs-to-a-container