# Search a data from large excel file with python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, excel, pyspark, azure-functions

I have very large excel file on my local. Whenever I try to find some data it gets crashed every time due to heavy dataset.

I'm trying to find a solution in python and azure function so that I can find a data quickly without file crashing.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Save Large excel files in the Blob Storage provided by Azure to access, backup, recover faster and provided the Blob Storage client libraries for Python for working on blob files and below code taken from this MS [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python?tabs=managed-identity,roles-azure-portal,sign-in-azure-cli#setting-up) helps to read the files from blob storage.

**Step 1**:

Importing required packages for retrieving the file from the blob storage in Python Azure Functions:

```py
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

**Step 2**: Declare all the required fields like storage account name, storage account access key, container name and blob name in the format of key = 'value' in the code.

**Step 3**: Initialize the blob service client. For example,

```py
blob_service = BaseBlobService(
    account_name=storage_account_name,
    account_key=storage_account_key
)
```

```py
blob_sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(blob_container_name, blobName, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
blob_sas_url = blob_service.make_blob_url(blob_container_name, blobName, sas_token=blob_sas_token)
```

In Python, **[pandas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-science-process/explore-data-blob)** library is used to work on large Excel Files for performing the operations like reading, analyzing, retrieving the data from and to the big Excel files.

**Read the Excel File using `pandas` library with `read_excel` method**:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(blob_sas_url)
print(df)
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63841801) for ways of reading the excel files from Azure Blob Storage using Python given by @*JimXu* and realpython's [article](https://realpython.com/working-with-large-excel-files-in-pandas/) if the file is stored in SQL Server and retrieving/reading the excel data using **`pandas`** framework to perform **`SQL-like queries`**.